# uikit 2.8.0 - How to set id for tab and retrieve it when selected

Tags: tabs, uikit

I am using uikit 2.8.0.

I am displaying vertical tabs in a view.

I want to set an id value to each tab and set value of selected id in a hidden variable so that I can post id value to server on form submission.

my tabs code:

[image: Code]

I tried following:

```
$('[data-uk-tab]').on('uk.switcher.show', function(event, area){
    alert(area[0].tabIndex);
    alert(area[0].value);
    alert(area[0].id);
});
```

tabIndex gives -1, value gives 0 and id gives no value.

How to set bank.id as tab index or tab id and retrieve it when tab is selected?

Thanks,
Suraj﻿

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem but couldn't find a direct solution.
In other tab that I have an horizontal tab and used successfully:

```
$('[data-uk-switcher]').on('uk.switcher.show', function(event, area){
    console.log("clicked="+area.context.id);
    if (area.context.id == 'preview_tab') {
        name = $("#topicEditForm_name").val();
        $("#preview_name").html(name);
    }
});
```

but it does not work in the vertical tab for some reason

I ebded up with a workaround: I've added a `<select>` button and used it to do the hidden input setting.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the `id="bank.id"` on the selector LI. then do `area.context.id`